# restricting selection of more than two checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html

When using two checkboxes,i can restrict selection of one checkbox at a time.How do i do this with more than one checkbox?
        Heres my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#checkbox1').click(function() {
        var checkedBox = $(this).attr("checked");
            if (checkedBox === true) {
                $("#checkbox2").attr('checked', false);
            } else {
                $("#checkbox2").removeAttr('checked');                    
            }
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#checkbox2').click(function() {
        var checkedBox = $(this).attr("checked");
            if (checkedBox === true) {
                $("#checkbox1").attr('checked', false);                     
            } else {
                $("#checkbox1").removeAttr('checked');                       
            }
        });
    });


$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#checkbox3').click(function() {
        var checkedBox = $(this).attr("checked");
            if (checkedBox === true) {
                $("#checkbox3").attr('checked', false);
            } else {
                $("#checkbox3").removeAttr('checked');                    
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

And my html code is as bellow

```
<i><input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="gold" />
        <label class="licencecheck" for="checkbox1"></label></i>
<i><input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="gold" />
        <label class="licencecheck" for="checkbox2"></label></i>
<i><input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" value="gold" />
        <label class="licencecheck" for="checkbox3"></label></i>
```

Comment: This is typically a usecase for `radio buttons`: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio

Comment: Where is the html?

Comment: oh damn,sorry...let me edit

Comment: theres the html

Comment: Why checkbox? Use Radio buttons

Comment: so type should be :type="radio"?tried that but its ruining my styling

Comment: used radio..and the third radio is still disabled,                                                 <i><input id="checkbox1" type="radio" name="checkbox1" value="gold" />
<label class="licencecheck" for="checkbox1"></label></i>

Comment: `ruined my styling` is not an reason to use the wrong elements :)

Comment: radio is also not working on the third radio button

Comment: i think theres an issue with the javascript.try it on your end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add common class to your check boxes for select them as a jQuery object collection and get the one that clicked and remove check attribute of others. Change your HTML and JavaScript into this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.my_checkbox').click(function() {
      $(".my_checkbox").not(this).attr('checked', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i><input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" class="my_checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="gold" />
        <label class="licencecheck" for="checkbox1"></label></i>
<i><input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" class="my_checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="gold" />
        <label class="licencecheck" for="checkbox2"></label></i>
<i><input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox"  class="my_checkbox" name="checkbox3" value="gold" />
        <label class="licencecheck" for="checkbox3"></label></i>
```

Comment: Although this is what OP asked, it's a 'miss use' of the checkbox type. There is a special type for this: radio

Comment: @ppasler I agree. But there are some special cases that I have seen in some applications.

Comment: This worked for me.There was an issue with the javascript.$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.my_checkbox').click(function() {
      $(".my_checkbox").not(this).attr('checked', false);
  });
});this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Use radio buttons for this case, this makes sure you can only select 1 element and works for unlimited radio buttons with the same `name`:

```html
<i>
  <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="group" value="gold" />
  <label class="licencecheck" for="radio1"></label>
</i>
<i>
  <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="group" value="copper" />
  <label class="licencecheck" for="radio2"></label>
</i>
<i>
  <input id="radio3" type="radio" name="group" value="silver" />
  <label class="licencecheck" for="radio3"></label>
</i>
```

Comment: the third radio button..now i see a radio button,and the check box sitting next to each other.I want the radio button to use the class"licencecheck"

Comment: @RILEY you should use same name for all the radio buttons. Ex: `name="radio-buttons"`